# A knot cannot be tied in 4-dimensions, but when was this conjectured and proven?

Tags: geometry, topology

Today it has been shown that a 1-dimensional object in 4-dimensional space cannot be tied into a knot.

But I would like to know who first conjectured this and when? And when was it proven?

(P.S., is there a hyper-dimension tag by some other synonym?)

Comment: What about [tag:knot-theory]?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A nice account is found in a note to R. Steiner's *Die vierte Dimension* ([1995](https://archive.org/details/rudolf-steiner-ga-324a/page/n235); [translation](https://books.google.com/books?id=SzsKPk2PgQ0C&pg=PT228)):

> ***Felix Klein*** (1845–1925) seems to have been the first mathematician to draw attention to this phenomenon in the early 1870s. According to an account by Zöllner ([1878a](https://books.google.com/books?id=qKoPAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA276)), Klein spoke with him during a scientific conference on this subject shortly before publishing a treatise ([1876](http://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/img/?PID=GDZPPN002243350&physid=phys485)) in which he discussed this theme in passing. Klein also reported on their meeting (...) ([1926, pp. 169ff](https://books.google.com/books?id=XtunBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA170)). While Klein ([1876, p. 478](http://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/img/?PID=GDZPPN002243350&physid=phys487)) discusses the subject only in general terms, Hoppe ([1879](https://books.google.com/books?id=CLIEAAAAQAAJ&pg=RA1-PA224)) uses an analytically formulated example to untie concretely a simple three-dimensional knot in four-dimensional space (see also Durège ([1880](https://books.google.com/books?id=EIU6AQAAIAAJ&pg=RA1-PA135)) and Hoppe ([1880](https://books.google.com/books?id=VagEAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA423))).

Klein is also credited by Tait ([1877](https://books.google.com/books?id=Uq49AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA190); [1882](https://books.google.com/books?id=xT5IPDMtSJYC&pg=PA129)), Dehn-Heegaard ([1907](https://archive.org/stream/encyklomath1103encyrich#page/n195)), and himself ([1922, p. 67](https://archive.org/stream/gesammeltema02kleirich#page/n80)).

**Edit.** To your additional question: Klein clearly convinced the experts that it wasn't just a conjecture. While he apparently never published his proof, I would bet he used the now-standard argument that one can eliminate one crossing at a time, as in e.g. Seifert-Threlfall ([1934](http://www.emis.de/cgi-bin/JFM-item?60.0496.05), [Remark 1](https://books.google.com/books?id=rsb8zjP0XHoC&pg=PA328)), Weitzenböck ([1929](http://www.emis.de/cgi-bin/JFM-item?55.0382.08), [§5](https://books.google.com/books?id=KBScBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA71)) or — maybe a first? — the last four paragraphs of Durège ([1880](https://books.google.com/books?id=IyAXAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA175)).

Comment: Okay, so Klein did general conjecture, and Hoppe only showed that **one specific type** of knot is not possible in 4D. But I'm hoping someone knows when the general case was proven, that **no type** of knot can exist in 4D.